# git --version displays wrong version on Terminal

Tags: git, macos, shell, terminal, homebrew

I am using homebrew to update git.  I typed:
`brew install git`

And homebrew tells me git 2.28 is already installed and up-to-date.  But, when I type:

`git --version`

I get:

`git version 2.15.0`

Why might this be happening and how do I fix it?

I've read that it might have to do with the $PATH, which I do not fully understand.  When I type
`which git`

I get:
`/usr/local/bin/git`

Comment: Does it work if you run git from a new terminal?

Comment: thanks, I think I figured out the issue.  It was already installed; it just wasn't linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah.  Now I figured out the issue.

I needed to update my shell.  Then, when I typed `brew install git` it said:

`Warning: git 2.28.0 is already installed, it's just not linked`

So I typed

`brew link git`

To link the version.

Comment: ``brew link --overwrite git`` This helped me